# What is a good word to describe 'exceptional positive' research work?

Tags: word-choice

In a sentence, when talking about future, for a person with huge potential.

> X has the potential for some ? research in Y field.

I was thinking

- game changing
- revolutionary

but both of these do not convey the right meaning.

Is there some other word that will serve the purpose here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say X has the potential for [**seminal**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seminal) research.

> **seminal**
>   **4.** highly original and influencing the development of future events: *a seminal artist*; *seminal ideas*.

If you don't want to make such an extreme prediction, I would go with Rimmer's suggestion of *groundbreaking*.

Answer (score 5):

What about [*groundbreaking*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/groundbreaking)?

> Innovative; new, different; doing something that has never been done before.

Answer (score 4):

How about *pioneering*? This often seems to be used for breakthrough medical research in particular.

There's also *cutting-edge*, *bleeding-edge* and the like, which are commonly used in technical fields.